# Bitwise operations on different sized data types

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation

I am trying to concatenate two Bytes, defined as `p1` and `p2` to form an Int `pnum`, and this is the implementation I came up with

```
pnum = p1 << 8
pnum |= p2
```

But a test case fails, when one of the numbers is negative (i.e has the MSB set), it is converted to an `Int` and the MSB is moved to the 32nd bit instead of the 8th, producing an incorrect value

What is the correct way to concatenate these two bytes, or preserving the MSB of the byte during the conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mask it before adding the `p2` bits (also masked).

```
val pnum = p1 << 8 & 0xFF00 | p2 & 0xFF
```